# Client to post video wordpress dynamic

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am a newly minted WordPress developer. One of my clients runs a small private institution. To help their students, they post video and PDF material. In my opinion, I would rather give the user another role than give them admin access. For example, I need to create a layout for the video page and when my client posts a video, it needs to be dynamically added to the page. Would it be possible to make my life easier with a plugin? That way, I will not have to help them in the future. I have already done it for the PDF part. It does not work to add video as the post.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to create a custom post type for videos. And use ACF plugin to add video details on backend and dynamically display the videos as posts in the template.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I found the plugin that works well for my needs.
Attached is the plugin URL for future reference (https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-video-gallery/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the plugin that works well for my needs. Attached is the plugin URL for future reference ([wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-video-gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-video-gallery/))